# Converting ISO8601 (I think) to hours:minutes:seconds in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, time

I'm not sure if this is going to be a simple answer or not. I tried searching for ways to convert ISO times online and I believe ISO 8601 is the time format I'm dealing with but I'm not 100% sure, and I couldn't find much info about it.

To keep it super short, in an XML document I'm parsing in Powershell, there is a duration field written as "PT8M51.693S" which is equal to 8:51.693, or 8 minutes and 51.693 seconds. I would like to convert it to "8:51" or "08:51". Anyone have any idea how I would do this? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Get out of here with this wizardry. How does powershell know what characters are the hours, minutes, and seconds?

Comment: Also, it returns an error with this message: "Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1"."

Comment: *How does powershell know what characters are the hours, minutes, and seconds?* PowerShell does not know that. It is `[Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan` responsibility to parse XML compliant duration and return .NET `TimeSpan` object. *Also, it returns an error with this message* So, you are using PowerShell v2, then try like this: `$ts = [Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan("PT8M51.693S"); '{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f ($ts.Hours+$ts.Days*24), $ts.Minutes, $ts.Seconds`.

Comment: Oh ok I understand a bit better now. Your answer worked correctly, so thanks a ton for that.

Comment: Great!  @PetSerAl, please post this as an answer; I think this is worth having the information searchable.
Matthew, please accept the answer.  This will properly retire the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `[Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan` to convert from XML duration type to .NET `TimeSpan` type. And for converting `TimeSpan` object to string representation in desired format, you can use PowerShell format operator `-f`:

```
$ts = [Xml.XmlConvert]::ToTimeSpan("PT8M51.693S")
'{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}' -f ($ts.Hours+$ts.Days*24), $ts.Minutes, $ts.Seconds
```